# How to properly delete from DOM javascript?

Tags: javascript

## What I'm doing

1. let `test` = `custom js code` that `add Event Listeners to #c1 Elements`
2. Create `<script #js>` `</script>`
3. Append `test` to `#js`
4. Delete `<script #js>` `</script>` **((( This is a problem )))**
5. `Add Event Listeners to #c2 Elements`
6. Delete `.box6` **((( This is a problem )))**

**Problem 4**
Even when I delete the `<script #js>` `Custom Code Appened for #c1 Elements` `</script>`, 
`#c1 Elements` are still clickable… they act as if `<script #js>` is still there.

**Problem 6**
Is this truly deleted from memory… or is it similar to Problem 4… meaning it's there… just not seeable. If it's still in memory… How to delete it?



**Heads Up** 
This is a universal problem… not just for `Event Listeners`, but `console.log`, `alerts`,… Once `<script #js>` is delete… nothing should be happening associated with `<script #js>` All this should be gone from memory.

## Working Demo

```js
let test = `
let container = document.getElementById("c1")
let clicked = container.getElementsByClassName("boxes");

for (let i = 0; i < clicked.length; i++) {
  clicked[i].addEventListener('click', b);
}

function b() {
if(this.classList.contains("clicked")) {
this.classList.remove("clicked");
}
else {this.classList.add("clicked");}
}
`;



// Creating Script Tag with #js
// And appending -test- var to it
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.id = 'js';
script.text = test;
document.body.appendChild(script);



// I deleted #js
// Yet #c1 .boxes event listeners are still attached to divs?
// They are not suppose to be clickable if I deleted #js
// What's going on
let deleteScript = document.getElementById('js');
deleteScript.parentNode.removeChild( deleteScript );


// This code will stay here
let container2 = document.getElementById("c2")
let clicked2 = container2.getElementsByClassName("boxes");
for (let i = 0; i < clicked2.length; i++) {
  clicked2[i].addEventListener('click', b2);
}
function b2() {
if(this.classList.contains("clicked2")) {
this.classList.remove("clicked2");
}
else {this.classList.add("clicked2");}
}



// I deleted .box6
// How to remove it properly from DOM… Out of memory
let deleteDiv = document.getElementById('here');
deleteDiv.parentNode.removeChild( deleteDiv );
```

```css
body {
  background: #E7F0F6;
}

.container {
  width: calc(100%-20px);
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.boxes {
  width: 25%;
  height: 80px;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #36BCFF;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: .3s;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #E7F0F6;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.boxes:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #36BCFF, 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}


.clicked {
  background: #36BCFF;
  color: white;
}


.clicked2 {
  background: #637182;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="c1" class="container">
  <div class="boxes box1">1</div>
  <div class="boxes box2">2</div>
  <div class="boxes box3">3</div>
  <div class="boxes box4">4</div>
</div>
<div id="c2" class="container">
  <div class="boxes box5">5</div>
  <div id="here" class="boxes box6">6</div>
  <div class="boxes box7">7</div>
  <div class="boxes box8">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Scripts are cached by browser. The best thing to do is write code that counteracts code behavior that's no longer desired. ex. `addEventListener()` vs `removeEventListener()`, `setTimeout()` vs. `clearTimeout()`

Comment: You need to code in a different manner, or rather with a different approach if you want to remove what your code has done. Browser caches scripts and they are available even if removed

Comment: So basically if I create a `script` set a main `function` with a time limit of  `1 hour`. As long as timer is going `execute all code within function` once timer is up `everything in it stops` and if I have not want to delete `script` lower the time to `1 second` then delete

Comment: Thus, killing everything inside?

Comment: And If time hits `10s` before I delete `script` add `1 hour` to timer

Comment: Or I could do……

Comment: add an `Event Listener` to `script`

Comment: If `data-js-live="true"` execute code in this function

Comment: else… don't run function

Answer (score 1):

You can not delete a script tag that caused the browser to evaluate some code and expect it to be gone.
But you can use removeEventListener in order to unregister event listeners,
And you can manipulate variables functions that has been declared using the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done... A script tag evaluates as soon as the script tag  is rendered. And can't be undone or disabled. You need to recreate the element or remove it's event listener that is attached to a DOM element.

It is erased from memory by the garbage collector no longer can be referensed from somewhere